# Convert number input into hh:mm Google Sheets

Tags: regex, time, google-sheets, formatting, array-formulas

I work for a fire department and we are switching to Google Sheets to track our run times. I am wondering if there is a way to take input such as "1356" and have it auto convert to time "13:56" so that elapsed time can be measured (we have to keep track of time from being dispatched to on scene). I know that I can format it after input but I would prefer to do this automatically if possible otherwise I have to have everyone input the colon as well so that it can be measured correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3&"", "(\d+)..$")&":"&REGEXEXTRACT(A3&"", "(\d{2}$)")
```

[image: 0]

---

and then additionally wrap it into `TIMEVALUE`

[image: 0]

---

for array use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A&"", "(\d+)..$")&":"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A&"", "(\d{2}$)"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @player0 answer, you can also do it formatting the cells where you will put the time.

Let's say you have **L** column to put the times. You have to select the column and create a new format for it:

[image]

On the **Custom number formats** you can set the format to be 00:00 for mm:ss or 00:00:00 for hh:mm:ss

[image]

And once applied you will just have to insert the time.

If you want seconds then: ss

If you want minutes and seconds then: mmss

If you want hours, minutes and seconds then: hhmmss